# How Do I Configure Changable Connection Strings in a Powershell Binary Module?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, powershell-module

I have a PowerShell module I wrote in C# which using Entity Framework to access a MS SQL server. In my project I have created a module.psd1 file. This file specifies a script (LoadAppConfig.ps1) to run before loading the dll. The script reads app.config and adds the connection string to the current app domain.

Is there a better way to do this? I know some modules can take parameters when you load them, but I haven't been able to find a way to implement this in C#. Or, is there a way to embed a default value in the module, which can be changed by a cmdlet? I would like to avoid having to recompile the module to change data sources if possible.

LoadAppConfig.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
$path = $PSScriptRoot
$configPath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath "App.Config"
$connectionstrings = [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::ConnectionStrings
$collection = [System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection]
$field = $collection.GetField(
    "bReadOnly",
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)
$field.SetValue($connectionstrings, $false)
[xml]$xml = gc $configPath
$name = $xml.configuration.connectionStrings.add.name
$newconnectionstring = $xml.configuration.connectionStrings.add.connectionString
$provider = "System.Data.EntityClient"

if ($connectionstrings.name -notcontains $name)
{
    $Entities = [System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings]::new($name, $newconnectionstring, $provider)
    $connectionstrings.add($Entities)
}
```

Comment: Provide some code what you are trying... Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask question.

Comment: I created an enum of environments and used that as a parameter. I can specify `-Env dev` or `-Env test,prod` to run on the various environments. I kept the connection strings in a settings file. It wasn't perfect but it works.